# Why address of code segment is zero?

Tags: gcc, position-independent-code

After I updated my kali linux, then I use gcc to compile my program. Before I updated the system, I used objdump to disassembly the program, the .text address is from 0x08048..., but after that, the .text address is from 0x00000..., the gcc version was changed from 6.1.1 to 6.3, what's wrong? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's because new version builds executables with `-fPIE` by default ([prooflink](https://bugs.kali.org/view.php?id=3764)). Position-independency should theoretically improve security of the system.

Comment: Thank you. With compile option -fno-pie and -no-pie, the problem has been solved.